# Cursor inside Procedure taking too Long to Run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-optimization

I want to optimize the performance of the cursor used below or deploy some other method to achieve the desired outcome which is much faster than the cursor used below. Currently, the cursor is able to operate on 1000 customers in 5 mins which leads to an estimated runtime of 1250 mins (per month) for about 250,000 customers on average per month.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 for my exercise. The cursor is inside a procedure which runs monthly. The month parameter for the procedure is @month_key (datetime variable) which is not declared in the code given below. Please keep in mind that the procedure needs to be run for 10 years of data and the below code is the most time consuming part of the procedure run.

```
--DECLARING VARIABLES 
DECLARE @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG DATETIME;
DECLARE @I INT;
DECLARE @CUSTOMER INT;
DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME;
DECLARE @EVENT_FLAG INT;
DECLARE @EVENT_CURSOR CURSOR;


---CURSOR 
SET @EVENT_CURSOR = CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NO 
FROM EVENT_DRV  
OPEN @EVENT_CURSOR;
FETCH NEXT FROM @EVENT_CURSOR INTO 
@CUSTOMER;

--EVENT FLAG
SET @EVENT_FLAG = (SELECT CASE WHEN DEF_FLAG = 1 THEN 1
WHEN (YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(WRT_OFF_DTE) and MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(WRT_OFF_DTE)) THEN 1 
WHEN  DATEDIFF(MONTH,A.MONTH_KEY,WRT_OFF_DTE) = 1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END
FROM EVENT_DRV A INNER JOIN EVENT_VAR B ON A.CUSTOMER_NO = B.CUSTOMER_NO AND A.MONTH_KEY = B.MONTH_KEY
WHERE A.CUSTOMER_NO=@CUSTOMER AND A.MONTH_KEY = DATEADD(MONTH,-12,@MONTH_KEY)) 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

SET @I =12;
WHILE (@I >=0)
BEGIN
    SET @I=@I-1 ;
    SET @START_DATE=DATEADD(MONTH,-@I, @MONTH_KEY)


    SET @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG = (SELECT CASE WHEN YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(DEF_MONTH_1) AND MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(DEF_MONTH_1) THEN 1
       WHEN (YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(WRT_OFF_DTE) and MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(WRT_OFF_DTE)) THEN 1 
       WHEN  DATEDIFF(MONTH,A.MONTH_KEY,WRT_OFF_DTE) = 1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 
      END  
      FROM EVENT_DRV A INNER JOIN EVENT_VAR B
        ON A.MONTH_KEY=B.MONTH_KEY AND A.CUSTOMER_NO = B.CUSTOMER_NO
      WHERE A.CUSTOMER_NO = @CUSTOMER AND A.MONTH_KEY = @START_DATE)

    IF @EVENT_FLAG = 0 AND @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG = 1
    BEGIN
    UPDATE  EVENT_DRV 
    SET EVENT_DRV.def_flag_final =1 
    WHERE MONTH_KEY=DATEADD(MONTH,-12,@MONTH_KEY)
    BREAK
    END
END  
FETCH NEXT FROM @EVENT_CURSOR INTO @CUSTOMER;
END
CLOSE @EVENT_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE @EVENT_CURSOR;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Are you missing relevant indexes or something similar?

Comment: Assume you using a cursor to process each customer individually.  This approach doesn't play to SQLs strengths, as a set based language.   Have you considered refactoring this as 1 query?  With samples of your tables and expected output we can help if you get stuck.

Comment: how many rows in `EVENT_VAR`?

Comment: @Devart: There are about ~250,000 rows for each month in EVENT_VAR. The procedure actually inserts data monthly into EVENT_VAR (and EVENT_DRV) and the cursor code is part of the monthly procedure run.

Comment: The best way to speed up a cursor is to **eliminate it** entirely.....

Comment: Elimitate the cursor and write a proper UPDATE  statement. 250K rows isn't a lot of data. A cursor though will ignore any indexes and result in **the slowest, most expensive execution possible**, generating log entries for every single row. As a comparison, you can process million-row table joins and complex calculations in minutes on an i7 64GB machine, and even that's considered slow.

Comment: @JamesBlond: Yes. I looked at the execution plan. The major load is at the inner join process and then the table scan for EVENT_DRV and EVENT_VAR and the update step.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
      @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG DATETIME
    , @CUSTOMER INT
    , @EVENT_FLAG INT
    , @MONTH_KEY DATETIME

SELECT @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG =
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(DEF_MONTH_1) AND MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(DEF_MONTH_1))
        OR 
            (YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(WRT_OFF_DTE) AND MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(WRT_OFF_DTE))
        OR
            DATEDIFF(MONTH,A.MONTH_KEY,WRT_OFF_DTE) = 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END  
FROM EVENT_DRV A
JOIN EVENT_VAR B ON A.MONTH_KEY = B.MONTH_KEY AND A.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO
--WHERE -- !!

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NO 
    FROM dbo.EVENT_DRV
    WHERE @EVENT_12_MONTH_FLAG = 1

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @CUSTOMER

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

     SELECT @EVENT_FLAG = 
        CASE
            WHEN
                    DEF_FLAG = 1
                OR
                    DATEDIFF(MONTH, A.MONTH_KEY, WRT_OFF_DTE) = 1
                OR
                    (YEAR(A.MONTH_KEY) = YEAR(WRT_OFF_DTE) AND MONTH(A.MONTH_KEY) = MONTH(WRT_OFF_DTE))
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM dbo.EVENT_DRV A
    JOIN dbo.EVENT_VAR B ON A.MONTH_KEY = B.MONTH_KEY AND A.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO -- !!
    WHERE A.CUSTOMER_NO = @CUSTOMER
        AND A.MONTH_KEY = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @MONTH_KEY)

    IF @EVENT_FLAG = 0 BEGIN

        UPDATE EVENT_DRV 
        SET EVENT_DRV.def_flag_final = 1 
        WHERE MONTH_KEY = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @MONTH_KEY)
            AND CUSTOMER_NO = @CUSTOMER -- !!

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @CUSTOMER

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

it's hard to understanding your business logic... anyway check this code

Comment: Nothing improves speed or simplifies queries as much as eliminating cursors